# Why is LaTeX math support on CSTheory so different from that of MathOverflow?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked this question on [Meta.CSTheory](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/485/873), and the moderator suggested I ask it here.

To cut a long story short, the math support on MathOverflow (even on [faketestsite](http://faketestsite.stackexchange.com/)) is much better than the support on CSTheory.

Specifically, when asking or answering a question, MO renders the formulas on the fly, while in CSTheory it takes quite some time before the formulas are processed.

I wanted to know how to tweak MathJax on CSTheory to behave like MO?

PS: I use Chrome (in fact, a Chromium-based browser named SRWare Iron) to access both sites (under Windows XP).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MathOverflow's previewing code is specifically tweaked to enable live-preview of equations, while on SE 2.0 sites we reuse SO's code highlighting procedure so there's a 5-second delay. See [this answer to *LaTeX rendering delay* on math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/689/latex-rendering-delay/705#705) by @Anton Geraschenko (admin of MO) for how to make it work like MO.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one question, though: Instead of using "User Scripts", is it possible to tweak previewing code on CSTheory, just like MO?

Comment: @Sadeq: Yes, but so far no one from the SE team confirmed whether it is `[status-declined]` or `[status-planned]`.